# Creating a table in android using intelliJ 12

Tags: android-layout

I am completely new to android and need to create a table with two columns and multiple rows to hold dates and associated information about those dates in the right hand column. I am using IntelliJ (latest version). Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) component for simple tabular data.  There are tutorials to be found out there, eg: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_table-layout/

Alternatively, if your data is more dynamic (could change as you view it), perhaps some sort of custom [ListView with adapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) is more suitable, have a look at the discussion here for more info:
[ListView or TableLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152833/listview-or-tablelayout)

Answer (score 0):

Delete existing main.xml and create a new main.xml with TableLayout.
Now in Property Window for TableLayout, set StretchColumn value to 2
Now for example, just click once on a "TextView" in the Palette and leave mouse, and then move your mouse to Designer Window.
You will see it will show you places to put your TextView Control. If you click again then you will be able to place the control (View). 
It will be automatically nested inside TableRow so no need to worry about that !