# Tablelayout or custum listView layout

Tags: java, android, android-tablelayout

Can anyone tell me on what layout i need to use to create this type of view in android. I thought of going with `TableLayout`, but i am not sure on this.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: table layout could work. listview as well, provided your column have a pre-measured width

Comment: I don't see why one shouldn't use a TableLayout in this case. It's certainly possible to do this with other layouts, but that's what tables are for. Here is a very elaborate answer on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12154874/368354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of the sheet is dynamic, then perhaps a `ListView` would be more apropriate, as the only thing you'll have to do in order to update the list, will be to notify the adapter that the dataset has been changed.

Another option to consider would be an `ExpandableListView`. This differs from the ListView by allowing two levels: groups which can individually be expanded to show its children.

(The `ExpandableListView` can be set to be expanded by default, if you don't want to have it expandable.)

Comment: Will my each box make a listView or one ListView for all the boxes.