# Is there any possible way to make this custom list?

Tags: android, custom-lists

Is there any possible way to do the android custom listview like in the image below? 
Custom adapter should have another listview as below.[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is either another widget or it simulates a table by using custom cells that have several 'columns' and probably rows.

Comment: You can use TableLayout instead of custom listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, the rows of the above illustration is not equally sized. It is possible to create it yourself if your plan is to dinamically build up the list item, but maybe it would be a relatively big task ("re-inventing the wheel", if you know what I mean). Here you can find a SO topic about what you should consider when you have to choose between `ListView` or `TableLayout`, which can be another solution:

[ListView or TableLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152833/listview-or-tablelayout)

In my humble opinion: because what we can see on your image is a table and ***not*** a list, it should be made with TableLayout.

If it is your opinion too, here is the official tutorial guide for TableLayout... ;)

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "2"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "Firt column title"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff"/ >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1.5"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "Second column title"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:gravity = "center"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "third column title"
        android:textColor = "#ffffff" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id = "@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:divider = "@null"/>
```

cell_shape.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:left = "-2dp"
    android:top = "-2dp">
    <shape android:shape = "rectangle" >
        <solid android:color = "@android:color/transparent" />

        <stroke
            android:width = "1dp"
            android:color = "@color/colorCell" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

listview_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:background = "@color/colorCell" >

    <TextView       
        android:id = "@+id/sNo"      
        android:layout_width = "0dp"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:background = "@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:ellipsize = "end"
        android:padding = "5dp"
        android:text = "categorie"
        android:singleLine = "true" />

<ListView
    android:id = "@+id/listview_first section list"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:divider = "@null"/>
<ListView
    android:id = "@+id/listview_number_section_list"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:divider = "@null"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My object is every category with List. then why do I need to use the two listview and textview? Could you please edit the answer

Comment: look at this example hope will help you